# How can I build RDKits C# Wrappers — Visual Studio 2019 x64

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cmake, swig, rdkit

I have followed the steps described here: https://github.com/bp-kelley/rdkit-csharp to try and create RDKits C# Wrappers.

```
git clone https://github.com/bp-kelley/rdkit-csharp.git
git clone https://github.com/rdkit/rdkit.git
cd rdkit-csharp
build.bat
```

While trying running the `build.bat` I've run into an error to do with creating named generators (among many others) and I'm not sure how to sort it out.

The `build.bat` references `Visual Studio 14` and `Visual Studio 14 Win64` I have tried to update this to `Visual Studio 16 2019` a few different ways. It seems to say that architecture should be referenced with an `-A` flag, but I've had no luck setting that.

If anyone can offer any direction at all for how to build this, I'd be most grateful. I'm finding it very tricky.

```
CMake Error: Could not create named generator Visual Studio 16 Win64

Generators
* Visual Studio 16 2019        = Generates Visual Studio 2019 project files.
                                 Use -A option to specify architecture.
  Visual Studio 15 2017 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2017 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 14 2015 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2015 project files.
```

In case it's helpful here's more

```
D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit-csharp\build64>cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 Win64" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX= -DRDK_BUILD_PYTHON_WRAPPERS=OFF -DRDK_BUILD_SWIG_WRAPPERS=ON -DRDK_BUILD_SWIG_JAVA_WRAPPER=OFF -DRDK_BUILD_SWIG_CSHARP_WRAPPER=ON -DBOOST_INCLUDEDIR="D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit-csharp\Nuget.Local/boost.1.69.0.0/lib/native/include" -DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR="D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit-csharp\Nuget.Local/lib64" -DBoost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON -DEIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR="D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit-csharp\Nuget.Local/Eigen.3.3.3/build/native/include" -DRDK_INSTALL_INTREE=OFF -DCPACK_INSTALL_PREFIX=rdkit -DRDK_BUILD_THREADSAFE_SSS=ON -DRDK_BUILD_AVALON_SUPPORT=ON -DRDK_BUILD_INCHI_SUPPORT=ON -DRDK_BUILD_CPP_TESTS=ON -DRDK_BUILD_CAIRO_SUPPORT=ON -DCAIRO_INCLUDE_DIRS="D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit-csharp\Nuget.Local/cairo.1.12.18.0/build/native/include" -DCAIRO_LIBRARIES="D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit-csharp\Nuget.Local\cairo.1.12.18.0\build\native\lib\x64\v120\Release\dynamic\cairo.lib" ..\..\rdkit
CMake Error: Could not create named generator Visual Studio 16 Win64

Generators
* Visual Studio 16 2019        = Generates Visual Studio 2019 project files.
                                 Use -A option to specify architecture.
  Visual Studio 15 2017 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2017 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 14 2015 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2015 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 12 2013 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2013 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 11 2012 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2012 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 10 2010 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2010 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "IA64".
  Visual Studio 9 2008 [arch]  = Generates Visual Studio 2008 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "IA64".
  Borland Makefiles            = Generates Borland makefiles.
  NMake Makefiles              = Generates NMake makefiles.
  NMake Makefiles JOM          = Generates JOM makefiles.
  Green Hills MULTI            = Generates Green Hills MULTI files
                                 (experimental, work-in-progress).
  MSYS Makefiles               = Generates MSYS makefiles.
  MinGW Makefiles              = Generates a make file for use with
                                 mingw32-make.
  Unix Makefiles               = Generates standard UNIX makefiles.
  Ninja                        = Generates build.ninja files.
  Watcom WMake                 = Generates Watcom WMake makefiles.
  CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - NMake Makefiles = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - NMake Makefiles JOM
                               = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - Ninja           = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles  = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeLite - MinGW Makefiles   = Generates CodeLite project files.
  CodeLite - NMake Makefiles   = Generates CodeLite project files.
  CodeLite - Ninja             = Generates CodeLite project files.
  CodeLite - Unix Makefiles    = Generates CodeLite project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - MinGW Makefiles
                               = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - NMake Makefiles
                               = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - Ninja       = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - Unix Makefiles
                               = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Kate - MinGW Makefiles       = Generates Kate project files.
  Kate - NMake Makefiles       = Generates Kate project files.
  Kate - Ninja                 = Generates Kate project files.
  Kate - Unix Makefiles        = Generates Kate project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - NMake Makefiles
                               = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - MinGW Makefiles
                               = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - Ninja         = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles= Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.


D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit-csharp\build64>msbuild "ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" /m /p:PlatformTarget=x64 /p:Configuration=Release /maxcpucount:4 /t:Build
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.7.3056.0
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.42000]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: ALL_BUILD.vcxproj

D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit-csharp\build64>copy Code\JavaWrappers\csharp_wrapper\Release\RDKFuncs.dll Code\JavaWrappers\csharp_wrapper
The system cannot find the path specified.

D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit-csharp\build64>copy ..\..\rdkit\Code\JavaWrappers\csharp_wrapper\RDKit2DotNet.csproj Code\JavaWrappers\csharp_wrapper
The system cannot find the path specified.
        0 file(s) copied.

D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit-csharp\build64>robocopy ..\..\rdkit\Code\JavaWrappers\csharp_wrapper\swig_csharp Code\JavaWrappers\csharp_wrapper\swig_csharp /E

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : 10 May 2019 23:26:05
   Source : D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit\Code\JavaWrappers\csharp_wrapper\swig_csharp\
     Dest : D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit-csharp\build64\Code\JavaWrappers\csharp_wrapper\swig_csharp\

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /S /E /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

2019/05/10 23:26:05 ERROR 2 (0x00000002) Accessing Source Directory D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit\Code\JavaWrappers\csharp_wrapper\swig_csharp\
The system cannot find the file specified.

D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit-csharp\build64>copy D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit-csharp\\RDKit.cs  Code\JavaWrappers\csharp_wrapper\swig_csharp\RDKit.cs
The system cannot find the path specified.
        0 file(s) copied.

D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit-csharp\build64>msbuild "Code\JavaWrappers\csharp_wrapper\RDKit2DotNet.csproj" /m /p:Configuration=Release /maxcpucount:4 /t:Build /p:Platform=AnyCPU
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.7.3056.0
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.42000]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: Code\JavaWrappers\csharp_wrapper\RDKit2DotNet.csproj

D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit-csharp\build64>REM build x86

D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit-csharp\build64>cd D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit-csharp\

D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit-csharp>mkdir build32

D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit-csharp>cd build32

D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit-csharp\build32>cmake -G "Visual Studio 16" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX= -DRDK_BUILD_PYTHON_WRAPPERS=OFF -DRDK_BUILD_SWIG_WRAPPERS=ON -DRDK_BUILD_SWIG_JAVA_WRAPPER=OFF -DRDK_BUILD_SWIG_CSHARP_WRAPPER=ON -DBOOST_INCLUDEDIR="D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit-csharp\Nuget.Local/boost.1.69.0.0/lib/native/include" -DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR="D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit-csharp\Nuget.Local/lib32" -DBoost_USE_STATIC-LIBS=ON -DEIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR="D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit-csharp\Nuget.Local/Eigen.3.3.3/build/native/include" -DRDK_INSTALL_INTREE=OFF -DCPACK_INSTALL_PREFIX=rdkit -DRDK_BUILD_THREADSAFE_SSS=ON -DRDK_BUILD_AVALON_SUPPORT=ON -DRDK_BUILD_INCHI_SUPPORT=ON -DRDK_BUILD_CPP_TESTS=ON -DRDK_BUILD_CAIRO_SUPPORT=ON -DCAIRO_INCLUDE_DIRS="D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit-csharp\Nuget.Local/cairo.1.12.18.0/build/native/include" -DCAIRO_LIBRARIES="D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit-csharp\Nuget.Local\cairo.1.12.18.0\build\native\lib\Win32\v120\Release\dynamic\cairo.lib" ..\..\rdkit
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.17763.0 to target Windows 10.0.17134.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.20.27508.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.20.27508.1
-- Check for working C compiler: D:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.20.27508/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: D:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.20.27508/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: D:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.20.27508/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: D:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.20.27508/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Check if the system is big endian
-- Searching 16 bit integer
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of unsigned short
-- Check size of unsigned short - done
-- Using unsigned short
-- Check if the system is big endian - little endian
-- Catch not found in D:/Desktop/Build/rdkit/External/catch/catch
Downloading https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/archive/v2.1.2.tar.gz...
CATCH: D:/Desktop/Build/rdkit/External/catch/catch/single_include
-- Could NOT find InChI in system locations (missing: INCHI_LIBRARY INCHI_INCLUDE_DIR)
Downloading http://www.inchi-trust.org/download/105/INCHI-1-SRC.zip...
-- Boost version: 1.69.0
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - not found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Could NOT find Boost
== Using strict rotor definition
Downloading http://sourceforge.net/projects/avalontoolkit/files/AvalonToolkit_1.2/AvalonToolkit_1.2.0.source.tar...
-- maeparser include dir set as 'maeparser_INCLUDE_DIRS-NOTFOUND'
-- maeparser libraries set as 'maeparser_LIBRARIES-NOTFOUND'
-- Could NOT find maeparser (missing: maeparser_INCLUDE_DIRS maeparser_LIBRARIES)
Downloading https://github.com/schrodinger/maeparser/archive/v1.1.tar.gz...
CMake Error at D:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2147 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.69.0

  Boost include path:
  D:/Desktop/Build/rdkit-csharp/Nuget.Local/boost.1.69.0.0/lib/native/include


  Could not find the following Boost libraries:

          boost_system
          boost_iostreams

  Some (but not all) of the required Boost libraries were found.  You may
  need to install these additional Boost libraries.  Alternatively, set
  BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT
  to the location of Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  External/CoordGen/CMakeLists.txt:39 (find_package)


-- coordgen include dir set as coordgen_INCLUDE_DIRS-NOTFOUND
-- coordgen libraries set as 'coordgen_LIBRARIES-NOTFOUND'
-- coordgen templates file set as 'coordgen_TEMPLATE_FILE-NOTFOUND'
-- Could NOT find coordgen (missing: coordgen_INCLUDE_DIRS coordgen_LIBRARIES coordgen_TEMPLATE_FILE)
Downloading https://github.com/schrodinger/coordgenlibs/archive/v1.2.2.tar.gz...
-- Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR)
CMake Error at D:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2147 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.69.0

  Boost include path:
  D:/Desktop/Build/rdkit-csharp/Nuget.Local/boost.1.69.0.0/lib/native/include


  Could not find the following Boost libraries:

          boost_system
          boost_iostreams

  Some (but not all) of the required Boost libraries were found.  You may
  need to install these additional Boost libraries.  Alternatively, set
  BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT
  to the location of Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  Code/RDStreams/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)


-- Could NOT find Boost
CMake Error at D:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2147 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.69.0

  Boost include path:
  D:/Desktop/Build/rdkit-csharp/Nuget.Local/boost.1.69.0.0/lib/native/include


  Could not find the following Boost libraries:

          boost_system
          boost_iostreams

  Some (but not all) of the required Boost libraries were found.  You may
  need to install these additional Boost libraries.  Alternatively, set
  BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT
  to the location of Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  Code/GraphMol/FileParsers/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Could NOT find Boost
== Making EnumerateLibrary without boost Serialization support
== Making FilterCatalog without boost Serialization support
-- Found PythonInterp: D:/Program Files/Python36-32/python.exe (found version "3.6.3")
== Updating Filters.cpp from pains file
== Done updating pains files
-- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)
-- Found Cairo: D:/Desktop/Build/rdkit-csharp/Nuget.Local/cairo.1.12.18.0/build/native/include
== Making SubstructLibrary without boost Serialization support
Downloading https://github.com/Tencent/rapidjson/archive/v1.1.0.tar.gz...
-- Found SWIG: C:/swig/swig.exe (found version "4.0.0")
CMake Error at D:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2147 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.69.0

  Boost include path:
  D:/Desktop/Build/rdkit-csharp/Nuget.Local/boost.1.69.0.0/lib/native/include


  Could not find the following Boost libraries:

          boost_system
          boost_iostreams

  Some (but not all) of the required Boost libraries were found.  You may
  need to install these additional Boost libraries.  Alternatively, set
  BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT
  to the location of Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  Code/JavaWrappers/CMakeLists.txt:43 (find_package)


-- Could NOT find Boost
SUFFIX:
JAVA_LIBS: AvalonLib;avalon_clib;RDInchiLib;Inchi;RGroupDecomposition;SubstructLibrary;MolStandardize;FilterCatalog;Catalogs;FMCS;MolDraw2D;FileParsers;SmilesParse;Depictor;SubstructMatch;ChemReactions;Fingerprints;ChemTransforms;Subgraphs;GraphMol;DataStructs;Trajectory;Descriptors;PartialCharges;MolTransforms;DistGeomHelpers;DistGeometry;ForceFieldHelpers;ForceField;EigenSolvers;Optimizer;MolAlign;Alignment;SimDivPickers;RDGeometryLib;RDStreams;RDGeneral
CMake Warning (dev) at D:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/UseSWIG.cmake:600 (message):
  Policy CMP0078 is not set: UseSWIG generates standard target names.  Run
  "cmake --help-policy CMP0078" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  Code/JavaWrappers/csharp_wrapper/CMakeLists.txt:63 (SWIG_ADD_LIBRARY)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at D:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/UseSWIG.cmake:460 (message):
  Policy CMP0086 is not set: UseSWIG honors SWIG_MODULE_NAME via -module
  flag.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0086" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  D:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/UseSWIG.cmake:695 (SWIG_ADD_SOURCE_TO_MODULE)
  Code/JavaWrappers/csharp_wrapper/CMakeLists.txt:63 (SWIG_ADD_LIBRARY)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/Desktop/Build/rdkit-csharp/build32/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "D:/Desktop/Build/rdkit-csharp/build32/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit-csharp\build32>msbuild "ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" /m /p:PlatformTarget=x86 /p:Configuration=Release /maxcpucount:4 /t:Build
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.7.3056.0
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.42000]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: ALL_BUILD.vcxproj

D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit-csharp\build32>copy Code\JavaWrappers\csharp_wrapper\Release\RDKFuncs.dll Code\JavaWrappers\csharp_wrapper
The system cannot find the path specified.

D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit-csharp\build32>copy ..\..\rdkit\Code\JavaWrappers\csharp_wrapper\RDKit2DotNet.csproj Code\JavaWrappers\csharp_wrapper
        1 file(s) copied.

D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit-csharp\build32>robocopy ..\..\rdkit\Code\JavaWrappers\csharp_wrapper\swig_csharp Code\JavaWrappers\csharp_wrapper\swig_csharp /E

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : 10 May 2019 23:27:02
   Source : D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit\Code\JavaWrappers\csharp_wrapper\swig_csharp\
     Dest : D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit-csharp\build32\Code\JavaWrappers\csharp_wrapper\swig_csharp\

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /S /E /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

2019/05/10 23:27:02 ERROR 2 (0x00000002) Accessing Source Directory D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit\Code\JavaWrappers\csharp_wrapper\swig_csharp\
The system cannot find the file specified.

D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit-csharp\build32>copy D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit-csharp\\RDKit.cs  Code\JavaWrappers\csharp_wrapper\swig_csharp\RDKit.cs
The system cannot find the path specified.
        0 file(s) copied.

D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit-csharp\build32>msbuild "Code\JavaWrappers\csharp_wrapper\RDKit2DotNet.csproj" /m /p:Configuration=Release /maxcpucount:4 /t:Build /p:Platform=AnyCPU
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.7.3056.0
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.42000]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 10/05/2019 23:27:02.
     1>Project "D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit-csharp\build32\Code\JavaWrappers\csharp_wrapper\RDKit2DotNet.csproj" on node 1 (
       Build target(s)).
     1>PrepareForBuild:
         Creating directory "bin\Release\".
         Creating directory "obj\Release\".
       CoreCompile:
         C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prom
         pt /warn:4 /define:TRACE /highentropyva- /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Fra
         mework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Micros
         oft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microso
         ft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Micro
         soft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Refere
         nce Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Data.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Refe
         rence Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Referen
         ce Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Refere
         nce Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /debug:pdbonly /filealign:512 /opti
         mize+ /out:obj\Release\RDKit2DotNet.dll /target:library /utf8output
     1>CSC : warning CS2008: No source files specified [D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit-csharp\build32\Code\JavaWrappers\csharp_
       wrapper\RDKit2DotNet.csproj]
     1>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(3713,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy th
       e file "D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit-csharp\build32\Code\JavaWrappers\csharp_wrapper\RDKFuncs.dll" because it was not
       found. [D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit-csharp\build32\Code\JavaWrappers\csharp_wrapper\RDKit2DotNet.csproj]
     1>Done Building Project "D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit-csharp\build32\Code\JavaWrappers\csharp_wrapper\RDKit2DotNet.cspro
       j" (Build target(s)) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

       "D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit-csharp\build32\Code\JavaWrappers\csharp_wrapper\RDKit2DotNet.csproj" (Build target) (1)
       ->
       (CoreCompile target) ->
         CSC : warning CS2008: No source files specified [D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit-csharp\build32\Code\JavaWrappers\cshar
       p_wrapper\RDKit2DotNet.csproj]


       "D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit-csharp\build32\Code\JavaWrappers\csharp_wrapper\RDKit2DotNet.csproj" (Build target) (1)
       ->
       (_CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectoryAlways target) ->
         C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(3713,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy
       the file "D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit-csharp\build32\Code\JavaWrappers\csharp_wrapper\RDKFuncs.dll" because it was no
       t found. [D:\Desktop\Build\rdkit-csharp\build32\Code\JavaWrappers\csharp_wrapper\RDKit2DotNet.csproj]

    1 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your cmake call to this:

`cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64  ... [rest of your CMake options] ...`

Here is the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/generator/Visual%20Studio%2016%202019.html#platform-selection) for the different platform names (architectures) you can use with VS 2019.

As the error message in your question suggests, CMake used to support specifying `Win64` along with the Visual Studio version, like this: `"Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"`. However, they have stopped supporting that as of Visual Studio 16 2019, forcing us to use the `-A x64` approach.

Comment: Ah so that is correct, I have tried that. I was thrown by the `Win64` vs `x64`. It seems as though either would work?

Comment: @Sarcoma I added some more explanation to my answer. For Visual Studio 2019, you can only use the `-A x64` approach to specify the 64-bit architecture.